# How do I limit the time my neighbor's kids spend at my home?

Tags: parents, pre-teen, middle-childhood, play-time

My neighbor’s children (9, 10, 11 and 12 years old) frequently pop over to my house to play. They get permission from their parents and me. I love that we have young kids on our street, but they stay a long time, eat most of our snacks, and then I feel responsible for walking them (with my children in tow) a few doors home.

How do I get this situation under control?

Comment: Are these kids inviting themselves into your house?

Comment: What us the age?

Comment: @one2three No they get permission from their parents and I. They are different ages...9, 10, 11 and 12 years old

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Hide the snacks and limit what's available.
2. Ask them why they like playing at yours. It could be that they aren't being fed properly at home, or a tough situation is going on at home etc.
3. Ultimately it's your house.  You can timebox their visits.  It's easy as all you have to do is make clear what the times are and stick to them.
4. You can say no.  It isn't the end of the world for you to have some say as to what happens in your house.

Comment: there is a very simple phrase "it is time for you to go home now"

Answer (score 3):

Talk to the neighbors.

You don't have to be confrontational, just mention to the parents that their kids seem to be snacking a lot at your house, and you want to be sure they're not eating something they shouldn't be, or spoiling their appetite for dinner. Also find out if your kids are spending time at their house as well. It's possible your children are also eating their snacks as well, so it could turn into an equitable arrangement.

Generally you should make it a point to be on friendly terms with the parents of your kids' friends, for this and many other reasons. Remember not to be judgmental of other parents for the ways that their parenting may differ from yours.